# Rewrite URL Htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want redirect augias.eu to subdirectory augias.eu/fr.
Redirection is working fine but all the urls like augias.eu/fr/path are redirected to augias.eu/fr
I don't get it. The website is live.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^augias.eu [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.augias.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://augias.eu/fr/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

HTacces file of the /fr directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Do you have any other directives? Any other `.htaccess` files (perhaps in the `/fr` subdirectory - if that is a physical subdirectory)?

Comment: Indeed I edited the post

Comment: Are you hosting multiple domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main directory .htaccess file change this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://augias.eu/fr/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

to this one:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://augias.eu/fr/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

because `$1` represents the first value enclosed in `()`. In this case  match this expression `(.*)`.

And inside the /fr/ folder, edit or create a new .htaccess file with this content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /fr/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /fr/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Although, unless there are other directives we are not privy to (eg. another `.htaccess` file in the `/fr` subdirectory - if indeed that is a subdirectory - containing mod_rewrite directives) then this will result in a redirect-loop. (Assuming we are not redirecting to an external domain.)

Comment: I changed the code with addign $1 but still the same. Deleting the code in the htaccess of the subdirectory created a loop I think. I added in the post the htaccess subdirectory code..

Comment: @PaulMartinez: sorry, I did not know that you had another .htacces file in that subfolder containing also a wordpress. I have edited my answer to fit new scenario. Check it please.

Comment: @masterguru I thought you solved it. But I think there was just a slightly improvments : I can access to this path https://www.augias.eu/fr/le-projet/ but there is still a redirection on https://www.augias.eu/fr/contact/ , https://www.augias.eu/fr/news/ or all translated pages https://www.augias.eu/fr/en . I don't know what to think...

Comment: @PaulMartinez mmm... maybe a browser cache problem?  It seems to run well from my side right now.  Try to clean browser cache or try another browser, please

Comment: `RewriteRule . /fr/index.php [L]` - this would imply you have a _second_ WordPress installation in the subdirectory - which is not mentioned in the question? And if that's the case then the OPs code wouldn't have worked at all when `/fr/` was requested since it would have invoked the wrong WP installation (since it assumes a single WordPress installation in the root)?